# Fit text to one column in minipage environment & boxed columns one over the other in beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage

I am writing a code in beamer. And I want my slide to look like this:[image: Expected].
The code that I have written is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{.25\columnwidth}
        \fbox{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\columnwidth}
        \fbox{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
        \fbox{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    \fbox{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But what I am getting is this:
[image: Outcome]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First an off-topic comment: Do not use *lenghty text* on presentation slides.

Comment: Don't use fboxes on beamer slides. -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152525/error-with-fbox-in-beamer

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks you for both of your comments. But I REQUIRE it for some or other reason.

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use beamers column mechanism to create the desired layout:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}
                \lipsum[2]
            \end{minipage}}%
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
        \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
                \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}
                    \lipsum[2]
                \end{minipage}}%
            \end{column}
      \end{columns}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
        \end{column}    
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}
                \lipsum[2]
            \end{minipage}}%

                \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}
                    \lipsum[2]
                \end{minipage}}%
            \end{column}
      \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks again. May be one could put \centering in before \includegraphics.

Comment: @sreerajt Sure, if you want the image top be centred, just add `\centering` or put it in a `figure` environment, they are centred by default in beamer